# I can see traffic coming from google ads, even though I don't have any google ads running, how is that possible?

Tags: google-ads, referrer

I can see "googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads...." as a referrer on my website. However I am not running any google ads. So how am I getting the traffic?

Here's the complete URL

http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?output=html&h=250&slotname=5275434421&w=300&lmt=1311690266&flash=10.1.102&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.humbug.in%2Fsuperuser%2Fes%2Fpromiscuous-modo-con-intel-centrino-adelantado-n-6200-agn-tarjeta-inalambrica--214946.html&dt=1311690268347&bpp=3&shv=r20110713&jsv=r20110719&prev_slotnames=7553874535%2C5896307875%2C8590890981&correlator=1311690268052&frm=4&adk=3153418812&ga_vid=1396001617.1311690268&ga_sid=1311690268&ga_hid=558368546&ga_fc=1&u_tz=-180&u_his=1&u_java=0&u_h=1024&u_w=1280&u_ah=960&u_aw=1280&u_cd=24&u_nplug=6&u_nmime=22&biw=1263&bih=851&fu=0&ifi=4&dtd=441&xpc=T5MgG9EVV9&p=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.humbug.in

Comment: Are you seeing this in your referrer logs or somewhere else?

Comment: Do the keywords associated with the traffic match words you would expect?

Comment: Is it possible that someone else might be running ads to direct traffic to your site? e.g. Do you sell a product through affiliates?

Comment: @paulmorriss, yes in my wordpress referrer logs. Yes i do sell products through affiliates

Comment: I can confirm that using matched content (or auto ads involving matched content) will imitate incoming traffic from googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads. I'm concerned that such behavior causes same visitor to be counted twice in analytics (once for original source and once for doubleclick.net as referal) did anyone managed to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of your affiliates is likely paying for a Google AdWords campaign using their referral link to drive traffic to your site (and boost their sales). That's the simplest explanation, and therefore probably the most likely cause of the AdSense referrals you're seeing.

I've had affiliates take out ads to boost their sales before; a welcome side effect of running an affiliate program is that other people sometimes pay for advertising for you. As long as the ads they run aren't misleading, it's usually good for business.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently started using Google AdSense matched content on my site and I have also started to see these referrals. I would imagine they are click on the matched content that link to elsewhere on the site.

Comment: Can confirm. Same thing happened to me, so maybe it's that? Matched Content kind of does what it promises, but it's implement in a very awkward way reporting-wise.

Answer (score 0):

I also have a lot of referer from googleads.g.doubleclick.net
It was begin yerterday. When I was monitoring my site via Google analytic Real Time. I see a lot of traffic that viewing my page SG (http://sahamok.com/SG/). Actually, I have no page with that url, so that page will redirect to 404 page.
I check site status from wordpress admin panel (my site using wordpress self host). Then I saw a lot of refer traffic came from googleads.g.doubleclick.net.  I am not using any ads service to advertise my site. So I am not sure why I got traffic from there.
Today (the second day), traffic that viewing page SG event more. 
Below is an example of referring :

http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?output=html&h=280&slotname=2004453173&w=336&lmt=1352773787&flash=10.1.82&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsahamok.com%2Fpasar-modal%2Femiten%2Fsektor-barang-konsumsi-consumer-good-bei%2Fsub-sektor-farmasi%2F&dt=1352777783395&bpp=2&shv=r20121031&jsv=r20110914&prev_slotnames=5280245630&correlator=1352777783365&frm=20&adk=1037511723&ga_vid=1006615589.1352777706&ga_sid=1352777759&ga_hid=398003352&ga_fc=1&u_tz=420&u_his=2&u_java=1&u_h=768&u_w=1024&u_ah=738&u_aw=1024&u_cd=32&u_nplug=13&u_nmime=95&dff=arial&dfs=13&adx=22&ady=327&biw=1008&bih=591&eid=39482000&oid=3&fu=0&ifi=2&dtd=504&xpc=7X8giBVG2z&p=http%3A%2F%2Fsahamok.com

My site is running adsense service to display ads in my page, but my site is not using any ads service to get traffic from there.
I still not have any ideas why this happen.